# Struct and file

Tags: c, file, struct

I m new to programing and I wonder if anyone could explain to me how to memorate a line from a file in to a variable of a struct? And then print it?:")

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct{
    char name[100];
}p;
void function(FILE* pfile, p me)
{
    rewind(pfile);
    char buffer[100];
    fgets(buffer, 100, pfile);
    strcpy(me.name, buffer);
    printf("%s\n", me.name);
}
int main()
{
    FILE* pfile = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    p me;
    function(pfile, me);
    fclose(pfile);
    return 0;
}
```

/////This is the code in c. The file contains only a name(your choise);

Comment: Your posted code works with me. Please specify what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function(pfile, me);` passes a copy of `me` to `function();`.  Surely you want `function()` to affect's `main's` `me`.  Pass the address of `me` and change function signature.

```
void function(FILE* pfile, p *me) {
    rewind(pfile);
    if (fgets(me->name, sizeof me->name, pfile) == NULL) {
      me->name[0] = '\0';
    } 
}

int main(void) {
  FILE* pfile = fopen("text.txt", "r");
  if (pFile) {
    p me;
    function(pfile, &me);
    fclose(pfile);
    printf("<%s>\n", me.name);
  }
  return 0;
}
```